# Point variable to a subset of another variable in R

Tags: r, pointers, variables

I work with a big matrix in R and wish to assign a new variable pointing to a subset of that big matrix to easily check if the applied functions work well. That new variable should always output the current subset of the matrix.

The problem simplified:

```
a <- 1:10
b <- a[1:3]
# b ... 1, 2, 3

a <- 21:30
# I want b to be 21, 22, 23 now, instead of 1, 2, 3
```

The function `delayedAssign(x, value)` only lazy assigns a value to b once.

The c++ equivalent solution is

```
int a {1, 2, 3};
int &b {a.at(0)};
```

Thanks for your support!

Comment: Is it an option for you to use python instead of R? (I guess that would be much easier there)

Comment: why not make b a function? Can't see the point of a pointer. `b <- function() a[1:3]`